# No future date SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is a query that tags the order_date either in the 'less than 14 days' or 'less than 30 days' section. There's one order date that's a future date and it's also included in 'less than 14 days'.

I tried the following:

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 14 AND DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < GETDATE() THEN 'Less than 14 days'
```

Future date is still there. Please advise

Original code:

```
SELECT CS.cust_id, OH.order_date,
    CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 14 THEN 'Less than 14 days'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN 'Less than 30 days'
    END
 AS 'orderAge'
FROM customers AS CS
INNER JOIN order_headers AS OH ON OH.cust_id = CS.cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id, order_date;
```

Comment: but a negative number is < 14

Comment: Is DATEDIFF giving, say, 12 for an order date in the _past_ by 12 days, or in the _future_ by 12 days? If the former, is a date in the future going to be < 0? That would also be < 14, so you would need to first check for < 0 (for future dates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT CS.cust_id, OH.order_date,
        CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 0 THEN 'Future date'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 14 THEN 'Less than 14 days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN 'Less than 30 days'
        END
     AS 'orderAge'
    FROM customers AS CS
    INNER JOIN order_headers AS OH ON OH.cust_id = CS.cust_id
    ORDER BY cust_id, order_date;
```

Comment: I thought about this but Future date has to be excluded from query

Comment: Where OH.order_date < GETDATE()

Comment: adding WHERE order_date < GETDATE() works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try your code but use 0 as a boundary point.  You want positive return values of the DATEDIFF function only.

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) < 14 AND DATEDIFF(DD,OH.order_date, GETDATE()) > 0 THEN 'Less than 14 days'
```